# Refering to a theorem by its name

Tags: cleveref, amsthm

So I've seen [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12913/customizing-theorem-name) that you can actually have a personnalized theorem environment name but I was wondering if there was a way to refer to it as is. I've chosen the solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\swapnumbers % optional, of course
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section] % the main one
\newtheorem{lemma}[thm]{Lemma}
% other statement types
\theoremstyle{plain} % just in case the style had changed
\newcommand{\thistheoremname}{}
\newtheorem{genericthm}[thm]{\thistheoremname}
\newenvironment{namedthm}[1]
  {\renewcommand{\thistheoremname}{#1}%
   \begin{genericthm}}
  {\end{genericthm}}

\begin{document}

\section{Something}

A theorem

\begin{thm}
$1+1=2$.
\end{thm}

And a named theorem

\begin{namedthm}{Zorn's Lemma}[Zermelo]\label{zorn}
All well-behaved ordered sets have maximal elements.
\end{namedthm}

\end{document}
```

given by @egreg and I would like to have it say "by Zorn's Lemma" when I write

```
by \cref{zorn}.
```

I know that I don't technically need it since it shouldn't be something that changes but we never know. Maybe I could link it with a hyperlink hidden under the text "Zorn's lemma"?

Comment: The code in your question does not compile

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz just edited the part I had forgotten

Answer (score 0):

Using the same trick as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/709531/36296

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\swapnumbers % optional, of course
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section] % the main one
\newtheorem{lemma}[thm]{Lemma}
% other statement types
\theoremstyle{plain} % just in case the style had changed
\newcommand{\thistheoremname}{}
\newtheorem{genericthm}[thm]{\thistheoremname}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentEnvironment{namedthm}{ m o }
  {\renewcommand{\thistheoremname}{#1}%
   \begin{genericthm}[#2]
   \def\@currentlabelname{#1}
   }
  {\end{genericthm}}
\makeatother  
\usepackage{nameref}

\begin{document}

\section{Something}

A theorem

\begin{thm}
$1+1=2$.
\end{thm}

And a named theorem

\begin{namedthm}{Zorn's Lemma}[Zermelo]\label{zorn}
All well-behaved ordered sets have maximal elements.
\end{namedthm}



by \nameref{zorn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see no need to make a big distinction between named and unnamed (but numbered) theorem-like environments. In fact, depending on the context, I think it's useful to be able to refer to a given theorem-like environment either by its number or by its name. The latter may be achieved with the help of the `hyperref` package and its `\hypertarget`/`\hyperlink` pair of macros.

Of course, if you create unnumbered theorems, you can still use the `\hypertarget`/`\hyperlink` mechanism to create textual cross-references to them.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}[\hypertarget{Zorn}{Zorn's Lemma}]\label{thm:zorn}
All well-behaved ordered sets have maximal elements.
\end{thm}

By \cref{thm:zorn}, \dots

By \hyperlink{Zorn}{Zorn's Lemma}, \dots

\end{document}
```